# MySpace iOS SDK 401 Error

Tags: ios, sdk, myspace

I'm working on adding support for MySpace in my application, and I think I've written everything correctly, but I seem to be getting a 401 error when the MSRequest delegate method is called. I would be happy to post my source code for those who are willing to help! Thanks, Derek

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your code I can't say much but a 401 is a bad auth code. How do you generate whatever OAuth token you need for their XHR requests? I'd start by looking there, post some source for more help.

Comment: This is the viewcontroller in which I have the user login: http://pastie.org/private/9wufw6dbbc87qslopfk7rw                             This is the controller where the actual post occurs:http://pastie.org/private/6mwarb2bsnonyphjphg                   The authentication key in the myspace api is written to a plist and then I grab the the authentication key in the class that posts the information to myspace. If anyone could help out that would be great!

Comment: i think there's an issue writing to plists from device. I find that if I edit a plist in one view/controller and try to use it in another view/controller that the changed data doesn't persist. It seems to work pretty well in simulator but I think it's just one of those things.